# Adding JS webresource to use in velocity

Tags: javascript, java, jira, jira-plugin

I'm new to Jira plugin development and I'm trying to develop a project tab panel plugin for JIRA (6.3.4).

I've JS file at *"resources/js/updateIssueTypes.js"* and it doesn't work in velocity template.

**JS file is not downloaded to the page**

**Where is a mistake?**

Here are the contents of the JS file:

```
$(function() {
    alert("haha");
    $("#selectedProject").change(function () {
        var key = $(this).val();
        $("#selectedIssueType").empty();
        $.getJSON("/rest/api/2/project/" + key, function(data) {
            var items = data.issueTypes;
            $.each(data, function( key, val ) {
                var option = $('<option/>');
                option.attr({'value': val.id }).text(val.nameTranslation);
                $('#selectedIssueType').append(option);
            });
        });
    })
});
```

velocity file has contents like this:

```
<head>
#requireResource("ru.company.plugins.postfunctions.Newtask:updateIssueTypes")
</head>
<body>
some code...
</body>
```

atlassian-plugin.xml has webresources added like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<atlassian-plugin key="${atlassian.plugin.key}" name="${project.name}" plugins-version="2">
  <plugin-info>
    <description>${project.description}</description>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <vendor name="${project.organization.name}" url="${project.organization.url}"/>
    <param name="plugin-icon">images/pluginIcon.png</param>
    <param name="plugin-logo">images/pluginLogo.png</param>
  </plugin-info>

  <!-- add our i18n resource -->
  <resource type="i18n" name="i18n" location="i18n"/>

  <!-- add our web resources -->
  <web-resource key="new-task-resources" name="new-task Web Resources">
    <resource type="download" name="images/" location="resources/images"/>
    <context>new-task</context>
  </web-resource>


  <web-resource key="updateIssueTypes" name="updateIssueTypes" >
    <resource type="download" name="updateIssueTypes" location="js/updateIssueTypes.js"/>
    <context>new-task</context>
    <context>atl.general</context>
    <context>jira.general</context>
  </web-resource>


  <workflow-function key="new-task" name="New Task" i18n-name-key="new-task" class="ru.company.jira.workflow.NewTaskFactory">
    <description key="new-task.description">The New Task Plugin</description>
    <function-class>ru.company.jira.workflow.NewTask</function-class>
    <resource type="velocity" name="view" location="templates/postfunctions/new-task.vm"/>
    <resource type="velocity" name="input-parameters" location="templates/postfunctions/new-task-input.vm"/>
    <resource type="velocity" name="edit-parameters" location="templates/postfunctions/new-task-input.vm"/>
  </workflow-function>
</atlassian-plugin>
```

pom.xml like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.company.plugins.postfunctions</groupId>
    <artifactId>Newtask</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
.......some code........
```

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't exactly a verbose problem description.

Comment: js file isn't downloaded to the page...

Answer (score 1):

**Resolved!**

**old version:**

```
<head>
#requireResource("ru.company.plugins.postfunctions.Newtask:updateIssueTypes")
</head>
```

**new version:**

```
<head>
</head>
$webResourceManager.requireResource("ru.eldorado.plugins.postfunctions.Newtask:new-task-resources")
```